# Program type already present: android.support.v7.appcompat.R

Tags: android, gradle, android-bundle, android-studio-3.2, android-d8

I'm facing issue while try to make bundle with following gradle and dependencies

project gradle:

```
buildscript { 
    ext.kotlin_version = '1.2.51'

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0-beta05'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }

        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        }
    }
    project.ext {
        build_tools_version="27.0.3"
        min_sdk_version=17
        target_sdk_version=27
        compile_sdk_version=27
        support_version = "27.1.1"
        google_play_services_version = "11.8.0"
    }
}
```

app gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation(name: 'GoogleConversionTrackingSdk-2.2.4', ext: 'jar')
implementation(name: 'leap_sdk', ext: 'aar')
implementation(name: 'SecureComponent-PROD-V1.5', ext: 'aar')
implementation(name: 'secure-component-sdk', ext: 'jar')
implementation project(':qrcodereaderview')
implementation project(':applib')
implementation project(':mapmarkerclustering')
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19'
implementation 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
implementation ('com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1')
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
        }
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.8.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0'
implementation ('com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0')
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
        }
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.3.0'
implementation 'commons-codec:commons-codec:20041127.091804'
implementation 'com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.0.0'
implementation ('com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:2.0.1')
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
            exclude module: 'support-v4'

        }
implementation 'com.squareup.wire:wire-runtime:1.6.1'
implementation 'com.squareup:tape:1.2.3'
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation('com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.1@aar') {
    transitive = true;
}
implementation('com.moengage:moe-android-sdk:9.1.04') {
    exclude group: 'com.moengage', module: 'moe-location-lib'
    exclude group: 'com.moengage', module: 'moe-push-firebase'
    exclude module: 'appcompat-v7'
}
implementation 'com.moengage:moe-push-gcm:3.1.00'
implementation ('com.moengage:addon-messaging:2.0.04')
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
        }

implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0'
implementation ('in.juspay:godel:0.6.24.1423')
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'

        }
implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.54.0.0'
implementation 'com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.54.0.0'

implementation 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0'
//Charts lib
implementation ('com.github.evgenyneu:js-evaluator-for-android:v2.0.0')
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
            exclude module: 'support-v4'

        }
implementation "com.android.support:customtabs:$support_version"
//SafetyNet dependency
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:${google_play_services_version}")
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
        }
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4+@aar'
implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0'
implementation('com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.8.5')
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
        }
implementation 'com.github.drawers:SpinnerDatePicker:1.0.4'
implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-core:$google_play_services_version"
implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:$google_play_services_version"

implementation 'com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4'
implementation "com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:${support_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:${support_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:cardview-v7:${support_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:${support_version}"
implementation "com.android.support:design:${support_version}"
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:${google_play_services_version}")
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
            exclude module: 'support-v4'

        }
implementation ("com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:${google_play_services_version}")
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
            exclude module: 'support-v4'

        }
implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:${google_play_services_version}")
        {
            exclude group: 'com.android.support'
            exclude module: 'support-v4'
        }

implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-config:$google_play_services_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:$kotlin_version"
implementation "com.android.support:support-v4:$support_version"
implementation (name: "razorpay-android-3.1.0", ext: 'aar')
implementation (name:"formbuilder-release", ext:'aar')
```

And dependency

```
+--- :GoogleConversionTrackingSdk-2.2.4
+--- :leap_sdk
+--- :SecureComponent-PROD-V1.5
+--- :secure-component-sdk
+--- project :qrcodereaderview
|    \--- com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0
+--- project :applib
|    +--- project :analytics-1.0
|    +--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.13 -> 2.2.22
|    |    \--- com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.4
|    +--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-s3:2.2.+ -> 2.2.22
|    |    \--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.22 (*)
|    +--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognito:2.2+ -> 2.2.22
|    |    \--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.22 (*)
|    \--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-cognitoidentityprovider:2.2.+ -> 2.2.22
|         \--- com.amazonaws:aws-android-sdk-core:2.2.22 (*)
+--- project :mapmarkerclustering
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:25.2.0 -> 27.0.2
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.0.3
|    |    |    |    |    |         +--- android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.0.3
|    |    |    |    |    |         \--- android.arch.core:common:1.0.0
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-media-compat:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    |    |    |         \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement-license:11.8.0
|    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0
|    |    |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks-license:11.8.0
|    |    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base-license:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps-license:11.8.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.8.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|         \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-location-license:11.8.0
+--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3
+--- com.mcxiaoke.volley:library:1.0.19
+--- com.squareup:otto:1.3.8
+--- com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.8.1
|    \--- com.jakewharton:butterknife-annotations:8.8.1
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.3.0 -> 1.8.0
+--- com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.7.0
|    \--- com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.2.0
+--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.3.0
|    \--- com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.3.0 (*)
+--- commons-codec:commons-codec:20041127.091804
+--- com.github.castorflex.smoothprogressbar:library-circular:1.0.0
+--- com.birbit:android-priority-jobqueue:2.0.1
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.8.0
+--- com.squareup.wire:wire-runtime:1.6.1
|    \--- com.squareup.okio:okio:1.2.0 -> 1.8.0
+--- com.squareup:tape:1.2.3
+--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.9.4
|    +--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.3
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics-core:2.6.3
|    |    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.2
|    |    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.3
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.3
|    +--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:beta:1.2.9
|    |    \--- io.fabric.sdk.android:fabric:1.4.3
|    \--- com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.2 (*)
+--- com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.1
|    \--- com.nineoldandroids:library:2.4.0
+--- com.moengage:moe-android-sdk:9.1.04
|    +--- com.moengage:moengagesdk:3.1.04
|    +--- com.moengage:pushbase:3.1.00
|    +--- com.moengage:inapp:3.1.00
|    +--- com.moengage:addon-messaging:3.1.00
|    \--- com.moengage:addon-realtime-trigger:2.1.01
+--- com.moengage:moe-push-gcm:3.1.00
+--- com.moengage:addon-messaging:2.0.04 -> 3.1.00
+--- com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.7.0
+--- in.juspay:godel:0.6.24.1423
|    \--- in.juspay:godel-osd:0.6.20
+--- com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.54.0.0
+--- com.madgag.spongycastle:prov:1.54.0.0
|    \--- com.madgag.spongycastle:core:1.54.0.0
+--- com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v3.0.0
+--- com.github.evgenyneu:js-evaluator-for-android:v2.0.0
+--- com.android.support:customtabs:27.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-safetynet-license:11.8.0
+--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2
|    \--- com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.1.2
+--- com.appsflyer:af-android-sdk:4+ -> 4.8.14
+--- com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:1.0
+--- com.firebase:firebase-jobdispatcher-with-gcm-dep:0.8.5
+--- com.github.drawers:SpinnerDatePicker:1.0.4
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.8.0
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.8.0
|         +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common-license:11.8.0
|         +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:11.8.0
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.8.0
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0 (*)
|         |    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|         |    |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid-license:11.8.0
|         |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0 (*)
|         |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|         |    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl-license:11.8.0
|         \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-license:11.8.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics-impl-license:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-api-license:11.8.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tagmanager-license:11.8.0
+--- com.github.clans:fab:1.6.4
+--- com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2 (*)
+--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2 (*)
+--- com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2
|    \--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
+--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2 (*)
+--- com.android.support:design:27.0.2
|    +--- com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-core-utils:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-fragment:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2
|    |    |    +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|    |    |    \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
|    |    \--- com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:27.0.2
|    |         +--- com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:27.0.2 (*)
|    |         \--- com.android.support:support-core-ui:27.0.2 (*)
|    +--- com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.2 (*)
|    \--- com.android.support:transition:27.0.2
|         +--- com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.2
|         \--- com.android.support:support-compat:27.0.2 (*)
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-iid-license:11.8.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm-license:11.8.0
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-appindexing-license:11.8.0
+--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-lite-license:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass:11.8.0
|    |    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    |    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-gass-license:11.8.0
|    \--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads-license:11.8.0
+--- com.google.firebase:firebase-config:11.8.0
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-basement:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-iid:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.firebase:firebase-common:11.8.0 (*)
|    +--- com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:11.8.0 (*)
|    \--- com.google.firebase:firebase-config-license:11.8.0
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.51
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.51
|         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.2.51
|         \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect:1.2.51
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.51 (*)
+--- :razorpay-android-3.1.0
+--- :formbuilder-release
\--- com.android.support:multidex:1.0.2 -> 1.0.3
```

*Caused by: com.android.tools.r8.errors.CompilationError: Program type already present: android.support.v7.appcompat.R
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.resolveClassConflictImpl(ProgramClassCollection.java:64)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.lambda$create$0(ProgramClassCollection.java:25)
    at java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.merge(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1990)
    at com.android.tools.r8.utils.ProgramClassCollection.create(ProgramClassCollection.java:24)
    at com.android.tools.r8.graph.LazyLoadedDexApplication$Builder.build(LazyLoadedDexApplication.java:124)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:123)
    at com.android.tools.r8.dex.ApplicationReader.read(ApplicationReader.java:86)
    at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:40)
    at com.android.tools.r8.GenerateMainDexList.run(GenerateMainDexList.java:110)
    at com.android.builder.multidex.D8MainDexList.generate(D8MainDexList.java:83)
    ... 52 more*

As per my understanding there are same lib with different version but unable to fix I already tried **exclude and configureAll** option

Answer (score 3):

I solved my problem by using following step:

1. update build tool to 28.0.2
2. update play-services lib
3. set `multidexEnabled false`
4. use dexgaurd with `-mutidex` option.